# Conexión Simple Con Java a MongoDb 3.4.2 No Se Encuentra El Método Authenticate

Tags: java, mongodb

Buenas, estoy intentando aprender MongoDb y me he quedado estancado durante varias horas en un simple método de conexión a la base de datos en java

He probado a seguir varios tutoriales pero parece ser que el metodo authenticate ya no existe os pongo mis dos intentos de métodos uno con metodos deprecados (que no me gustaría usar) y otro sin ellos

Os pongo tambien las variables que he usado:

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Conector.class.getName());

private static final String URLBBDD = "localhost";
private static final int PUERTOBBDD = 27017;
private static final String USUARIO = "usuario";
private static final String CONTRASENNA = "contrasenna";
```

Metodo deprecado:

```
public void conectarBaseDatosDeprecado() {

    try {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(URLBBDD, PUERTOBBDD);

        // getDB Deprecado
        DB baseDatosDeprecada = mongoClient.getDB("prueba");

        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conectando a Base De Datos: {0}...", baseDatosDeprecada.getName());

        // metodo authenticate no existe
        boolean auth = baseDatosDeprecada.authenticate(USUARIO, CONTRASENNA);

        if (auth) {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conexión Exitosa");
        } else {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conexión Fallida");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Excepcion Al Conectarse A La Base De Datos: {0}", e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Ahora os pongo el método que no usa deprecados:

```
public void conectarBaseDatos() {

        try {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(URLBBDD, PUERTOBBDD);

            MongoDatabase baseDatos = mongoClient.getDatabase("prueba");

            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conectando a Base De Datos: {0}...", baseDatos.getName());

            boolean auth = baseDatos.authenticate(USUARIO, CONTRASENNA);

            if (auth) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conexión Exitosa");
            } else {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Conexión Fallida");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Excepcion Al Conectarse A La Base De Datos: {0}", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

En ambos casos el método authenticate no lo encuentra y el Net Beans dice en esa misma línea para ambos casos:

Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase.authenticate

a pesar de que en la web se supone que va a mi no y creo que es por la version del driver (2.10.1), pero me gustaría saber si hay algún equivalente para la versión actualizada que estoy usando de mongoDB(3.4.2)

Toda la documentación que encuentro esta con la versión antigua

Muchas gracias por leerme y perdonad si está duplicado (estuve buscando pero no encontre algo parecido)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta como dice en [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_java.htm) así:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase; 
import com.mongodb.MongoClient; 
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;  

public class ConnectToDB { 

   public static void main( String args[] ) {  

      // Creating a Mongo client 
      MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

      // Creating Credentials 
      MongoCredential credential; 
      credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb", 
         "password".toCharArray()); 
      System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");  

      // Accessing the database 
      MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb"); 
      System.out.println("Credentials ::"+ credential);     
   } 
}
```